# Why is the port line in docker not filled in in the ollama project?

Tags: docker, ollama

I am running ollama in docker, but the port is not full.

[image]

The documentation says what to use
`docker run -d -v ollama:/root/.ollama -p 11434:11434 --name ollama ollama/ollama`
But I don't understand where to write it a little. To the ollama console?
If yes, then, as I understand it, you need to write the following command
`docker run d v ollama:/root/.ollama p 11434:11434 name ollama ollama/ollama`

But an error occurs, there is no such file.

I also checked Docker, and there is a file with that name

[image]

Tell me how you can launch the port and use the api to access ollama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run -d -v ollama:/root/.ollama -p 11434:11434 --name ollama ollama/ollama
```

> Do you have "ollama" file where you are running that command?
>
> `-v ollama:/root/.ollama` bind mount "ollama" from your current
> directory to inside container /root/.ollama
>
> If you don't have "ollama" file  download from
> https://ollama.ai/download <- here and place that file to the path
> where you will run docker command
>
> If you get zipped file, unzip it (the file name has to be same as
> "ollama")
>
> For example
>
> ```
> ls
> Ollama-darwin.zip Ollama.app
>
> pwd
> /Users/kade93/workspaces/ollama-run
>
> sudo docker run -d -v ollama:/root/.ollama -p 11434:11434 --name ollama ollama/ollama
> 4cb885920b9b7aaa0807434b2b04123574cad27573eecc820adc1f92a3d96fcf
>
> sudo docker exec -it 4cb885920b9b7aaa0807434b2b04123574cad27573eecc820adc1f92a3d96fcf bash
> root@4cb885920b9b:/# ls /root/.ollama/
> id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  models
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> sudo docker ps
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND               CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
> 4cb885920b9b   ollama/ollama   "/bin/ollama serve"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:11434->11434/tcp   ollama
> ```

### Result

Ollama file is not about the problem, can run without download ollama with docker

docker run can be avaliable without downdload ollama at local directory

Comment: yeah that's right I'll change it Thanks, I just tried to explain easily

Comment: I just don't understand where to run this command
`docker run -d -v ollama:/root/.ollama -p 11434:11434 --name ollama ollama/ollama`

Comment: I was able to download and run the project in Docker, but I can't figure out how to open the port.

Comment: Ollama is execution file , So it would be looks like Ollama.app not like your screenshot above .

So, what kind of shell (Mac OS iterm, linux terminal, or window powershell?)

I mean your command has to be same place where ollama file exist

Comment: I'll just edit my post

Comment: How do I run it in Docker Ollama.app?

Comment: Ollama is served by docker ( ollama.app mounted on docker container)

If you mean run llama2 on container

the command is


`docker exec -it ollama ollama run llama2`

Comment: And also look at here 

https://hub.docker.com/r/ollama/ollama

Comment: And how do I access the model via the API? Docker should open a port to allow me to access the model via the API.

Comment: I am very sorry if I am asking strange questions, I just don't understand how to do all this. The documentation says one thing, but in fact it's different.

Comment: what about checking
this link 

https://github.com/jmorganca/ollama/blob/main/docs/api.md

Comment: After properly run ollma with docker, you can curl to your localhost:11434 , if you use `curl localhost:11434` you have to get message
`Ollama is running%`

Comment: I understood what the mistake was. When deploying ollama in Docker, I needed to specify "0" as localhost, then I can access the model through the API. But thanks anyway

Comment: `-v ollama:/root/.ollama` does not bind 'ollama' from the current directory as you say. It creates a Docker volume called 'ollama' and binds that to `/root/.ollama` in the container.

Comment: Yeah I think @HansKilian is right, ollama is not necessary , it will create volume 
And the problem was not about ollama file , So i'll change my post

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).